# How to cast an object to Enum and get the current value in Java

Tags: java, enums

I have a field currently casted to object. I need to check if this field is a type of enum, and if so i would like to get the name of the currently set value. 
Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
If(field is an enum){
      get the value of the field
}
```

Where i am currently at

```
if (field.getClass().isEnum()){
    String enumValue =  //here i need to cast the field to enum and do something like field.name()
}
```

Comment: `field.toString()` comes to mind since internally it calls `Enum#name()`.

Comment: @Pshemo What if I've overriden it?

Comment: "*//here i need to cast the field to enum and do something like field.name()*" that is correct. What is stopping you from doing so? `String enumValue = ((Enum)field).name();` seems to do what you wanted. OR if you are sure that `toString` method wasn't overridden by that enum type you can call it to get name of enum value.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for pointing that out. Included alternative solution in second comment.

Comment: @Pshemo thanks for the answer. Can you write as an answer so that i can mark it as the solution ?

Comment: @blackened8333 I have posted an answer see if that works for you.

Comment: @blackened8333 Done: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58218205. I undeleted my original answer and edited it to add more details. I deleted it earlier since posted solution is actually what you yourself written in your comment which gives me impression that you ware aware of it but for some reasons didn't want to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on

> I have a field currently casted to object

I assume you have situation like `Object obj = SomeEnum.FOO;` and from

> i would like to get the *name* of the currently set value

I assume you would like to get `"FOO"` String.

If above assumptions are correct then what you written in

> `String enumValue =  //here i need to cast the field to enum and do something like field.name()`

should work for you. So when you are sure that `field` holds an enum value you can cast it to `Enum` type and call its `name()` method which returns a String representing enum value.

```
String enumValue = ((Enum)field).name();
```

In case when you are sure that enum doesn't override its `toString()` method you can also call it instead since by default it also returns `name` of enum.

```
String enumValue = field.toString(); //this solution looks nicer but first one is more reliable.
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have the value of the constant in the field just make `field.get(theObject);`

Comment: I suspect that you reversed the question. If I am not mistaken from "I have a field currently casted to object" we can assume situation like `Object obj = SomeEnum.FOO;`. If that is the case then by "i would like to get the name of the currently set value" OP probably wants to get `"FOO"` String (not an enum value which OP already has in a `field` variable). Using `YourEnum.valueOf` would require from us to actually know the `YourEnum` type which may not be known at time of writing the code. Also `valueOf` doesn't return a String but *takes* a String.

Comment: "*OP wants the enum connstant stored in the Field*" but if it is already stored in the field then OP already *has* it (in that `field`).